# Elasticsearch dsl OR query formation

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have index with multiple documents. The documents contains below fields:

- name
- adhar_number
- pan_number
- acc_number

I want to create a elasticsearch dsl query. For this query two inputs are available like adhar_number and pan_number. This query should match **OR Condition** on this.

Example:  If one document contains provided adhar_number only then I want that document too.

I have one dictionary with below contents (my_dict):

```
{
  "adhar_number": "123456789012",
  "pan_number": "BGPPG4315B"
}
```

I tried like below:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
s = Search(using=es, index="my_index")
for key, value in my_dict.items():
   s = s.query("match", **{key:value})

print(s.to_dict())
response = s.execute()
print(response.to_dict())
```

It creates below query:

```
{
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'must': [
        {
          'match': {
            'adhar_number': '123456789012'
          }
        },
        {
          'match': {
            'pan_number': 'BGPPG4315B'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Above code is providing me the result with **AND condition** instead of **OR Condition**.

Please suggest me the good suggestions to include OR Condition.

Answer (score 13):

To fix the ES query itself, all you need to do is use 'should' instead of 'must':

```
{
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'should': [
        {
          'match': {
            'adhar_number': '123456789012'
          }
        },
        {
          'match': {
            'pan_number': 'BGPPG4315B'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To achieve this in python, see the following example from [the docs](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html). The default logic is AND, but you can override it to OR as shown below.

> Query combination Query objects can be combined using logical
> operators:
>
> ```
> Q("match", title='python') | Q("match", title='django')
> # {"bool": {"should": [...]}}
>
> Q("match", title='python') & Q("match", title='django')
> # {"bool": {"must": [...]}}
>
> ~Q("match", title="python")
> # {"bool": {"must_not": [...]}}
> ```
>
> When you call the .query() method multiple times, the & operator will be used internally:
>
> ```
> s = s.query().query() print(s.to_dict())
> # {"query": {"bool": {...}}}
> ```
>
> If you want to have precise control over the query form, use the Q shortcut to directly construct the combined
> query:
>
> ```
> q = Q('bool',
>     must=[Q('match', title='python')],
>     should=[Q(...), Q(...)],
>     minimum_should_match=1 ) 
> s = Search().query(q)
> ```

So you want something like

```
q = Q('bool', should=[Q('match', **{key:value})])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) as also mentioned by @ifo20. Note that you most likely want ot define the [`minimum_should_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match) parameters as well:

> You can use the minimum_should_match parameter to specify the number or percentage of should clauses returned documents must match.
>
> If the bool query includes at least one should clause and no must or filter clauses, the default value is 1. Otherwise, the default value is 0.

```
{
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'should': [
        {
          'match': {
            'adhar_number': '123456789012'
          }
        },
        {
          'match': {
            'pan_number': 'BGPPG4315B'
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

Note also that the should clause contributes to the final score. I don't know how to avoid this but you may not want this to be part of an OR logic.